# How to configure alerts for employee contract expiration in odoo 11?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

i'm using odoo 11 and i want to know how can I configure odoo in a way that the HR manager and the employee received alert before the expiration of  contract.
Is it possible to do it ? Any idea for help please ?

Answer (score 0):

This type of scenario is only archived by developing custom addon.
In custom addon you have to specify cron file which will automatically fire some action at regular basis, and which will send email notification to HR Manager that some of employee's contract are going to be expired.